# What do I do with these "Omni Plants"?

Tags: the-sims-3

I just checked my Sim's inventory and saw these two gift boxes labelled "Omni Plant". They are not selectable, can't be dragged out of the inventory, and aren't plantable or anything (they're obviously not seeds). The sim who has them has 0 Gardening skill anyway.

I'm not using any mods or cheats. Is there some way I can use or remove these items or is it just yet another bug?

[image: omni plants]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug, and unfortunately you cannot use the Omni Plant even if you did have level 10 gardening.  See [this page](http://forum.thesims3.com/jforum/posts/list/402627.page#5694942) for details.  It sounds like the only option to get rid of them is through mods, Master Controller is one specifically mentioned as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Omni Plants are special plants that grow copies of whatever you feed them. Extremely rare, they can only be planted by Sims with a gardening skill of 10.

You can feed Omni Plants just about anything and harvest copies, except:

- Bicycles
- Cars
- Money bags
- Paintings
- Prepared food
- Recipes
- Rocks
- Seeds
- Stereos

I've never had gifts, so I don't know if you should be able to open the boxes and sell the content. It may be that you can just use the gift right away, and since you don't have a high enough gardening level, you can't interact with it. However, seeing how useful these plants can be, it may be worth it to learn how to garden.

Answer (score 0):

**It is definitely a bug, because of your sim having no gardening skill.** These are the only real ways you could get the Omni Plant:

- I used the BuyDeBug cheat and went to the 'seed spawners and plants' tab and if you dig around, you will find the Omni Plant. You will be able to plant it for free, same with the other plants that are there. That's one way to get it.
- Another way is if your sim has level 10 gardening skill and is offered a series of 3 opprtunities to get the Onmi plant and be able to order more via mailbox. That is a no-cheat way. But it's really hard. Your sim better know what it's doing  C; .

But that is really weird.

Hope this Helped!

Answer (score 0):

I got a stuck car in the inventory, but after taking vacation all items in my inventory were reshuffled and after that I was able to move out of the car.  Maybe this can help you remove the stuck items in your inventory.

Answer (score -3):

I got a house from The Sims 3 exchange and it had its own omni-plant.

My Sim harvested it and an option popped up when I clicked on it again, saying "Feed," so I wasn't thinking and fed it a Cookbook. The next day it had 2-4 cookbooks on it!

I went like, "WTF? This plant is really cool!" I think you can get it using the cheat (first put in `testingcheatsenabled true` cheat via the debug console). Go to the garden/plants/seeds one and I think it's there. I'm unsure, but that's the only place I can think of.